# "Subscribe for" vs. "subscribe to" updates

Tags: prepositions, expression-choice

What form is correct or more suitable when speaking about website updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be trying to say that you subscribed to something to get something else.

If you were to subscribe to updates, that means you are subscribing to the updates. The updates are going to give you something, and are not the thing being given. For example, I subscribed to updates in order to get free kittens. That makes Updates some weird organization or noun that gives kittens.

Subscribe for updates is much different. It means updates are what is being given to you. For example, I subscribed to Funnycatvideos to get updates on new hilarious cat videos. So you subscribed *to* Funnycatvideos and what you received was updates.

This means the second choice would fit your situation.

Comment: To summarise: I subscribe to blog for updates.

Comment: @AndrewBarchuk To _a_ blog. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Event vs. condition.  You must subscribe [event] for (in order to receive) the updates (the process of being updated); you subscribe [ongoing condition] to the updates.